# jQuery Change Divs from Active to Inactive on a Loop

Tags: jquery

I'm having a few issues making my code work the way I want it to. I want to be able to show different divs on a loop when a click action is made. I have attached the code in a snippet below. Ideally, when I click the button again I want it to go back to the first Div in the array and place an active class on the element.

It works when you first start it but when you go through the cycle again it doesn't work.

```js
var content = $('#rotationContent .central-text');

currentContent = 0;

function ChangeContent()
{
    currentContent++;
    newContent = currentContent + 1;
    
    if (newContent > content.length) {
        currentContent = 1;
        newContent = currentContent + 1;
        
        $('[data-id="' + content.length + '"]').removeClass('rotating__active').addClass('rotating__inactive');
        $('[data-id="' + currentContent + '"]').removeClass('rotating__inactive').addClass('rotating__active');
    } else {
        $('[data-id="' + currentContent + '"]').removeClass('rotating__active').addClass('rotating__inactive');
        $('[data-id="' + newContent + '"]').removeClass('rotating__inactive').addClass('rotating__active');
    }
    
    console.log(currentContent);
    console.log(newContent);
}
```

```css
.rotating__active {
    display: block;
}

.rotating__inactive {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotationContent" class="col-md-6 rotating__fixed">
  <div class="central-text rotating__active" data-id="1">
    <h3>RENT IT OUT</h3>
    <h4>Shout it from the rooftops</h4>
    <p>You’re never going to get your place rented if you don’t get it out there. We’ll get your ad onto all the major property sites, and a few of the smaller ones too.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="central-text rotating__inactive" data-id="2">
    <h3>MANAGE YOUR PROPERTIES</h3>
    <h4>All together in one place</h4>
    <p>Whether you’ve got one or 10 properties, manage them all in our state of the art management system. Rent collection records? Check. Repairs arranged? Check. 24/7 access? Check.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="central-text rotating__inactive" data-id="3">
    <h3>CHECK OUT YOUR TENANTS</h3>
    <h4>Get the best in through the door</h4>
    <p>Weed out the time wasters with our comprehensive referencing service. You’ll only get high-quality tenants legally entitled to rent in the UK.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="ChangeContent()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  When you step through the code in your debugger, what specifically happens?  Where specifically does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  What is the observed behavior on that line?  What was the expected behavior?  Why was it expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this much simpler function.

```js
var content = $('#rotationContent .central-text');
var currentContent = 1;

function ChangeContent() {
  currentContent++;
  if (currentContent > content.length) {
    currentContent = 1;
  }

  $('.central-text')
    .removeClass('rotating__active')
    .addClass('rotating__inactive');

  $('[data-id="' + currentContent + '"]')
    .removeClass('rotating__inactive')
    .addClass('rotating__active');
}
```

```css
.rotating__active {
    display: block;
}

.rotating__inactive {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotationContent" class="col-md-6 rotating__fixed">
  <div class="central-text rotating__active" data-id="1">
    <h3>RENT IT OUT</h3>
    <h4>Shout it from the rooftops</h4>
    <p>You’re never going to get your place rented if you don’t get it out there. We’ll get your ad onto all the major property sites, and a few of the smaller ones too.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="central-text rotating__inactive" data-id="2">
    <h3>MANAGE YOUR PROPERTIES</h3>
    <h4>All together in one place</h4>
    <p>Whether you’ve got one or 10 properties, manage them all in our state of the art management system. Rent collection records? Check. Repairs arranged? Check. 24/7 access? Check.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="central-text rotating__inactive" data-id="3">
    <h3>CHECK OUT YOUR TENANTS</h3>
    <h4>Get the best in through the door</h4>
    <p>Weed out the time wasters with our comprehensive referencing service. You’ll only get high-quality tenants legally entitled to rent in the UK.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="ChangeContent()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much Eric!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, much simpler

```js
var content = $('#rotationContent .central-text');

currentContent = 1;

function ChangeContent()
{
    $('.central-text').removeClass('rotating__active').addClass('rotating__inactive');
    $('[data-id="' + (currentContent%content.length+1) + '"]').removeClass('rotating__inactive').addClass('rotating__active');
currentContent++;
}
```

```css
.rotating__active {
    display: block;
}

.rotating__inactive {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotationContent" class="col-md-6 rotating__fixed">
  <div class="central-text rotating__active" data-id="1">
    <h3>RENT IT OUT</h3>
    <h4>Shout it from the rooftops</h4>
    <p>You’re never going to get your place rented if you don’t get it out there. We’ll get your ad onto all the major property sites, and a few of the smaller ones too.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="central-text rotating__inactive" data-id="2">
    <h3>MANAGE YOUR PROPERTIES</h3>
    <h4>All together in one place</h4>
    <p>Whether you’ve got one or 10 properties, manage them all in our state of the art management system. Rent collection records? Check. Repairs arranged? Check. 24/7 access? Check.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="central-text rotating__inactive" data-id="3">
    <h3>CHECK OUT YOUR TENANTS</h3>
    <h4>Get the best in through the door</h4>
    <p>Weed out the time wasters with our comprehensive referencing service. You’ll only get high-quality tenants legally entitled to rent in the UK.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="ChangeContent()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```